# warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int *’, but argument 5 has type ‘int’ [-Wformat=]

Tags: c++, c, linux, file

I don't know what's wrong. Imo it's correct, but i have such problem.
It's my first program in C connected with files, and i don't know, what i'm doing wrong.

```
2.c: In function ‘main’:
2.c:15:11: warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int *’, but argument 5 has type ‘int’ [-Wformat=]
 fscanf(fp,"%s %s %d\n", a,b,c);
           ^
```

My program

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    FILE *fp;
    FILE *fb;
    char z;
    char a[20], b[20];
    int c;
    fp=fopen("data.txt","r");
    fb=fopen("bigmoney.txt","a");
    while (z!=EOF)
    {
        z=fgetc(fp);
        fscanf(fp,"%s %s %d\n", a,b,c);
        if (c > 2000)
            fprintf(fb,"%s %s %d\n", a,b,c);
    }
}
```

File data.txt

```
Jan Nowak 2000
Irena Pierwsza 3000
Irena Druga    2500
Krzysztof Mrugala 3500
Tadeusz Pat 2000
Emiliusz Jeden 1200
Adam Arma 6000
Kornel Robo 5000
Jan Kowalski 15000
agf dahf 524
sdgdagf adgdagf 345345
adgadgf dfdfgh 1168510135
arek kowalski 3300
```

Comment: `fscanf(... %d ...)` is expecting a pointer, change to `fscanf(fp,"%s %s %d\n", a,b,&c);`, (notice the address of operator `&`), and you are usin `z` uninitialized in the first iteration of the `while` loop.

Comment: How much clearer can the error message be?  %d needs an `int*`, you are passing `int`.

Comment: Oh god, i'm just blind, i placed & in wrong place, thanx!

Answer (score 2):

Function `fscanf` (actually all `scanf`-variants) expect, for each format specifier, a *memory address* to where the values read in can be stored. So the arguments passed to `scanf` always have to be pointers to values, not the values.

The reason why it works with variables `a` and `b` but not with `c` is that `a` and `b` serve as pointers to a memory block of 20 consecutive characters, whereas `c` holds an integral value (not a pointer).

To overcome this, write `fscanf(fp,"%s %s %d\n", a,b,&c);`, such that you provide the memory in which the value of `c` is stored rather than the value of `c` itself.

Hope this helps.